# Peewee and Flask-Admin: View with only foreign keys missing attribute '_data'

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I use flask peewee together with flask-admin and it works fine for some model classes, but I got one model, that it does not work on and gives me the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'GroupMember' object has no attribute '_data'
```

This is how the model looks:

```py
class GroupMember(BaseModel):
   group = ForeignKeyField(Group)
   member = ForeignKeyField(Member)

    class Meta:
        primary_key = CompositeKey('group', 'member')
```

As this model consists of only foreign keys, I thought I would need to create a custom view that lists the columns explicitly, because by default flask-admin hides those columns.

I did so:

```py
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    column_list = ('group', 'member')
```

And initialized the view:
`admin.add_view(MyModelView(GroupMember))`

This honestly changed nothing and I still get the same error. I found related questions that mentioned "backrefs" - what would that do and how would I do this? Or is this even the reason for my problem?

Comment: Is this something you would really want to manage as a standalone thing? What about inlining the groups into the Users admin page?

Comment: With inlining you mean, that i embed the fields along with the User view? Do you have an example of how that would be done?
But actually, for the sake of a simple view, I think doing this standalone would suffice or be even better in this case. Also I'd like to figure out whats happening.

Comment: I tried updating the dependencies since new versions of flask-admin and peewee have been released but without success.